# How do you add the installation screen for your an electron app like atom, WhatsApp and others?

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I Have created my first app with electron but I am down with the question How do you add the installation screen for your an electron app like atom, WhatsApp and others?
I have seen this in several apps built with electron and I just don't see in the documentation

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this NPM package that creates Windows installers for Electron applications. https://github.com/Electron/Windows-Installer

Comment: Ohhh okay i think there is an idea fro there, using electron-squirel-window package with electron-builder

Answer (score 0):

you can use one of electron builder like [electron builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder) and as per configuration you have to mention icon property in your package.json like

```
"win": {
  "icon": "../icons/icon"
}
```